# How can I have all drupal links work on ajax based?

Tags: 7, ajax

Is it possible to have all drupal internal links work on ajax based without any page refresh?

If there is any ready module, please share the link. Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this module will help you: http://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api

> Ajax links API module help you to load any content to a specified DIV
>   using JQuery Ajax. This module will also load JS and CSS for
>   Ajax-loaded content by using Drupal.attachBehaviors(). Links will work
>   as normal if Javacript is disabled.
>
> In HTML5 browsers, title bar and url will change using
>   window.history.replaceState() (This feature is disabled by default.
>   Check ajax_links_api.js to enable).